# IOS Segue- detecting table cell and opening a viewController

Tags: ios, uitableview, uistoryboardsegue

i am new to ios programming. i have a static tableViewController  in which i have 3 cells. i have another view controller where there is a label and description. what i am trying to do is detect the cell which user clicks and then change the label which is in my second view controller according to that but the problem is whenever i click the cell the program crashes and added the breakpoint

here is my code

```
 - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
 {
      NSString *name;
      NSString *description;

    if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"PushAppDetailsFromCell1"] )
    {
        name = @"Label 1 ";
        description = @"Long description of Label 1...";
    }

    else if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"PushAppDetailsFromCell2"] )
    {
        name = @"Label 2";
        description = @"Long description of Label 2...";

    }
    else if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"PushAppDetailsFromCell3"] )
    {
        name = @"Label 3";
        description = @"Long description of Label 3...";
    }
        else {
            return;

}
        AppDetailsViewController *apDetailsViewController = 
        segue.destinationViewController;  //here i am getting the breakpoint
        apDetailsViewController.appDetails =
        [[AppDetails alloc] initWithName:name description:description];

}
```

**AppDetails.m**

```
-(id)initWithName:(NSString *)name description:(NSString *)descr{

    self = [super init];

    if(self){
        self.name = name;
        self.description = descr;

        }
    return self;
}
```

**AppDetailsViewController.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.nameLabel.text = self.appDetails.name;
    self.descriptionLabel.text = self.appDetails.description;

}
```

Comment: is appDetails kind of retained property in AppDetailsViewController? Make it @property (strong, nonatomic) AppDetails*appDetails;

Comment: yeah it is already like this ... i have declared it the same

Comment: are you sure application is crashing in  - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender ?

Comment: yeah when i click any cell of table it crashes and show me breakpoint here AppDetailsViewController *apDetailsViewController = 
segue.destinationViewController;

Comment: Your segue is bound with cell UITableViewCell or UITableView?

Comment: Check my answer and implement same way as I explained it will resolve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSArray *names = @[@"Label 1", @"Label2", @"Label 3"];
NSArray *descs = @[@"Description 1", @"Description", @"Description 3"];

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"PushAppDetailsSegue"]) {
         NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.yourTableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        AppDetailsViewController *controller = segue.destinationViewController;
        controller.appDetails = [[AppDetails alloc] initWithName:names[indexPath.row] description:descs[indexPath.row]];
    }
}
```

Drag a segue from your ViewController to SecondViewController and name it "PushAppDetailsSegue".

Answer (score 2):

Steps to figure out the problem

1) Put a break point in prepareForSegue

2) Try to see it displays correct segue id as it should be(there might be making spelling mistake).

3) see where it's crashing in

```
 - In prepareForSegue?
 - Is this calling initname()?
 - has it started it viewDidLoad().
```

If you do this mostly you will figure out what the problem is. If you can not then let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Bind segue from UIViewController to UIViewController rather then cell to UIViewController. Implement following code for navigation.

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"%ld",aIntSelected);
    NSLog(@"%@",segue.destinationViewController);
}
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   aIntSelected=indexPath.row;
   NSLog(@"didSelectRowAtIndexPath called");
   [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"pushSecond" sender:self];

}
```

Comment: Here from aIntSelected. You will get which row is selected.

Comment: yeah thanks i know i can do like this by using didselectrow method but  i want to know what is the problem in my code .. why it is not working as expected ..

Comment: i am following a tutorial from a book and i have written the exact code